Not able to click the save button in the dialog box
I am doing a web automation project using NodeJS with Playwright. The project is to scrape the links and open it in new tabs and save the PDFs. I reached the last part of saving the PDFs and I am stuck on this step. I tried several ways but I am not able to click the save button in the dialog box as shown in the image. I'd greatly appreciate if you can help me figure this out. Thank You.
I tried simulating the Enter keypress as follows:
await page.keyboard.press('Enter'); 
Also, I tried locating the save button in the dialog box and click it as follows:
// Wait for the print dialog to appear and interact with it
const printDialog = await context.waitForEvent('page');
await printDialog.waitForSelector('select.md-select');
await printDialog.selectOption('select.md-select', { label: 'Save as PDF' });

// Click the save button
await printDialog.click('cr-button.action-button'); 
Both ways are not working
What I want to do is to just click the save button when the print/save dialog box appears. The first dialog box appears within the browser; the second one appears outside the browser in the OS.
Below is the function which handles the opening of collected links in a new tab, and if the navigation is successful, it will click the button on a web page with the id "btn-print" and open the dialog box within the browser:
async function handlePdfLink(url, name) {
    const pdfPage = await context.newPage();
    const maxRetries = 4;
    let navigationSuccess = false;

    for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= maxRetries; attempt++) {
      try {
        console.log(`Attempt ${attempt} to load ${url}`);
        await pdfPage.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle', timeout: 60000 });
        navigationSuccess = true;
        break;
      } catch (error) {
        console.warn(`Attempt ${attempt} failed to load ${url}:`, error);
        if (attempt === maxRetries) {
          console.error(`Failed to load ${url} after ${maxRetries} attempts.`);
          failedUrls.push(url); // Add URL to failedUrls
        } else {
          await pdfPage.waitForTimeout(1000);
        }
      }
    }

    if (navigationSuccess) {
      try {
        // Wait for iframe and get its content frame
        const iframeElementHandle = await pdfPage.waitForSelector('iframe');
        const frame = await iframeElementHandle.contentFrame();

        if (!frame) {
          throw new Error('Could not get iframe content.');
        }

        // Click the print button inside the frame
        await frame.click('#btn-print');

        // Wait for the print dialog to appear and interact with it
        const printDialog = await context.waitForEvent('page');
        await printDialog.waitForSelector('select.md-select');
        await printDialog.selectOption('select.md-select', { label: 'Save as PDF' });

        // Click the save button
        await printDialog.click('cr-button.action-button');

        // Wait for the download to complete and save the file
        const download = await context.waitForEvent('download');
        const savePath = path.join(pdfDir, generateUniqueFileName(name));
        await download.saveAs(savePath);

        console.log(`Saved ${savePath}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error processing ${url}:`, error);
        failedUrls.push(url); // Add URL to failedUrls if an error occurs during processing
      }
    }

    await pdfPage.close();
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
  }


As far as I know Playwright dismisses the dialog boxes, so you need to handle the dialog boxes in a different way. I never had the opportunity to work with this, but it is documented here: https://playwright.dev/docs/dialogs
